# Graph user-defined function

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to graph this custom function, but I can't find how. Is it even possible? All examples are about known functions (like sin or exp(x)).

I get the following error:

```
error: myfun: A(I,J,...) = X: dimensions mismatch
error: called from
    myfun at line 28 column 16
    grafica1 at line 54 column 2
>>
```

Code:

```
function ph = myfun(gamma)
...

  for i = 1:N
    ....
        A(i,i) = alfa*gamma+(gamma+1)*i+p*(N-i);
      elseif j == i-1
        A(i,j) = -i*(i-1);
      elseif j == i+1
        A(i,j) = -p*(N-i)*(i-1)*(i+1)/i;
    ...
    b(i) = gamma * i;
  end

  v = A\b;
  for i = 1:N
    ph = ph + nchoosek(N,i)*p^i*v(i)/((1+p)^N);
  end

endfunction
```

call:

```
y=myfun(gamma);
plot(gamma,y)
```

Comment: What are `size(gamma)` and `size(y)`?  They should be vectors of equal length.

Comment: I didn´t define Y, acording to the variables panel, it is 3x1.  gamma=0:1:9;

Comment: Can you point which line is "myfun at line 28"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your function is that it not designed with vectorization in mind. Specifically, when the input `gamma` is a row vector, `alfa*gamma+(gamma+1)*i+p*(N-i);` must also be a vector. Of course it will fail if you assign its value to `A(i, j)`, which is a scalar.

I think your best option at this point is to **compute the y values one at a time.** This requires the least amount of change to your existing codebase.

```
y = zeros(size(gamma))
for i = 1:length(gamma)
  y(i) = myfun(gamma(i));       
end
plot(gamma, y);
```

Comment: or better, `y = arrayfun(@myfun, gamma);` instead of `y=myfun(gamma);`